# How to encapsulate a template hierarchy

Tags: php, xml, templates, template-engine

I'm looking for an elegant way to encapsulate/abstract the template structure of a website/application. Specifically, I need a way to determine which template to use, and when.

My research turned up a few articles about the Template Method pattern ([this one](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method) being the best I found), but that seems to address a distinct, related problem...

I'm thinking namely of the [WordPress heirarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png), which I'm familiar with. I find it arbitrary and constrictive. I need a structure I can define (using XML or something) in a concrete, easy-to-visualize way, but that I can change easily. The code to determine which template to use should not have to change as a result of the structure itself changing. That is, the template hierarchy and the  logic navigating it should be loosely coupled.

Is this even possible without magic?? Are there any design patterns/frameworks/cool tricks that address this successfully? Anything I can learn from, really. Thanks : )

Comment: It's a common approach my team uses in several platforms (ASP, .NET, and PHP).  Each page derives from single page class that adds menus, content, ads, etc.  We build the template in an in memory XML document, and the template class adds to it via XML methods.  This allows for easy re-brandnig, and no HTML in the code (we use XSL for that)